# Sort JSON by highest value PHP

Tags: php, json, sorting

I want to sort this JSON array by highest value in the imdb undervalue.

```
[{
    "name": "Space home",
    "year": 2012,
    "plot": "Ghost dies in fire",
    "run": 103,
    "run_category": "1",
    "rated": "PG-13",
    "imdb": 83,
    "meta": 82,
    "genre": "001 002 003",
    "tags": "test",
    "source": "movie123",
    "id": 6483953
}, {
    "name": "Epaaoon",
    "year": 2016,
    "plot": "Space dies in fire",
    "run": 153,
    "run_category": "2",
    "rated": "R",
    "imdb": 64,
    "meta": 54,
    "genre": "001 006 007",
    "tags": "test2",
    "source": "movie423",
    "id": 7352753
}]
```

I have tried:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {  function
return $a->imdb > $b->imdb ? -1 : 1; });
```

which I found here, but I cant get it to work and I have no idea why. Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../data.json'; 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
usort($data, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function

return $a->meta > $b->meta ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
});
print_r($data); 
?>
```

Comment: I think there's more to your code that we're missing. can you post a more complete example please.

Comment: Sorry! Updated with the complete php code.

Comment: Since you use `true` as the second argument, to `json_decode()`, the elements are arrays, not objects. So it's `$a['meta']`, not `$a->meta`.

Comment: you're accessing it via an object, but you've decoded it as an array. should be comparing $a['meta'] > $b['meta']

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either get rid of the `true` argument to `json_decode()`, or use `$a['meta']` and `$b['meta']` in the comparison function. The second argument to `json_decode()` tells it to convert JSON objects to PHP associative arrays rather than objects.